# To get the parent node of a treeview in the TreeViewDragDropTarget in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, treeview

I have created a TreeViewDragDropTarget like this,

```
<controlsToolKit:TreeViewDragDropTarget msWindows:DragDrop.AllowDrop="False" ItemDroppedOnTarget="TreeViewDragDropTarget_ItemDroppedOnTarget" ItemDragCompleted="TreeViewDragDropTarget_ItemDragCompleted" AllowedSourceEffects="Copy">
    <controlsToolKit:TreeViewDragDropTarget.Resources>
     <common:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="hierarchicalTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildNode}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding MainText, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
     </common:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </controlsToolKit:TreeViewDragDropTarget.Resources>
    <controls:TreeView x:Name="MainTreeView" BorderThickness="1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource hierarchicalTemplate}" Background="Transparent" Cursor="Hand" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
   </controlsToolKit:TreeViewDragDropTarget>
```

All I am doing is dropping some text into the nodes of the treeview. I want to find the parent node of the drop target. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Drop event of the treeview control.